# Zend framework v2.6 how to reset mysite.com/admin/login.php password in mysql from phpmyadmin database manually

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2, md5, reset

My previous developer had build mywebsite in Zend2.6 framework and it has a admin login panel to make changes on my website (like photos change and text changes etc) , I had used the credentials that my previous developer provided me but now I have lost it . So I want to change the password of my admin panel login . That need to log in to: mysite.com/admin/login.php.

I've created a username and password in the user table in phpMyAdmin (using md5 for the password) but I still can't log in .

How can I reset my user Table admin password?

Or Can I add another user into Users table? ( tried but didn’t work)

Password in database is in md5 encryption format.

How can I reset it from phpMyAdmin?

I did find a question related to this where an answer suggested to find “salt” and suffix it to the newpassword and fire update query on that DB Users table , that worked for him for zend V1 but how can I find “salt” on zend v2.6 to check if exists. Or any other method can help to reset/change password of admin panel login?

additional details: 
I have there ewcfg6.php , ewmysql6.php , userfn6.php etc.... inside ewcfg6.php stated define("EW_MD5_PASSWORD", FALSE, TRUE); // Use MD5 password define("EW_CASE_SENSITIVE_PASSWORD", FALSE, TRUE); // Case-sensitive password

this is also inside ewcfg6.php /** * Password (MD5 and case-sensitivity) * Note: If you enable MD5 password, make sure that the passwords in your * user table are stored as MD5 hash (32-character hexadecimal number) of the * clear text password. If you also use case-insensitive password, convert the * clear text passwords to lower case first before calculating MD5 hash. * Otherwise, existing users will not be able to login. MD5 hash is * irreversible, password will be reset during password recovery. */

Comment: Just MD5 is not safe. Normally SALT is being used. You should look into the code how to calculate right password hash with salt.

Comment: how it can be calculated? please help!

Comment: You must be misinformed. Latest ZF2 is  2.5.3. Since you have ewcfg6.php, looks like web-site was built with PHPMaker. Common config in ZF is stored in config/application.config.php. Your file ewcfg6.php contains EW_RANDOM_KEY. I guess this must be what you are looking for. So in most cases PASSWORD_HASH is MD5(PASSWORD_STRING+EW_RANDOM_KEY) or MD5(EW_RANDOM_KEY+PASSWORD_STRING)

Comment: tried above but can't login yet, Yes this website was by PHPMaker,and there is define("EW_ADMIN_USER_NAME",,) and define("EW_ADMIN_PASSWORD") as well , please help

Comment: if you have access to it in development, why would you not simply define a new password? at the very start of the file `public/index.php`, after `<?php` do the exact thing the password creation does, but replace the password with something of your own. So do `md5("new strong but still md5 password" . EW_RANDOM_KEY); exit;` and refresh the site. Save the printed output to your user records password field in the database.